# Getting location from GPS in ios8.0 App

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

Hi i am working on an ios app. I want to get the current location of the device using GPS. How can i get latitude and longitude of a place,and from them how can i determine current city name. I came across example from following http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/ but when i pressed the button nothing happened.I am using IOS simulator and i have changed the Debug --> Location --> to Apple.

I am developing for ios 8.0

Comment: You want to geocode to the address (get the GPS coordinate of a user entered text address). There is an example given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735981/geocoding-address-into-coordinates-in-iphone As for the get current city name, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 apple changes some plist keys and entry for location access..

Please follow the below step to keep your core work..

- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
  [See Apple document for plist.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)
- Before `startUpdatingLocation` & after allocation `CLLocationManager` add this code for location services permissions

```html
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
  [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```